# What retain policy should be used for an NSTimer property assigned to via scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval?

Tags: ios

I'm just about to add an NSTimer property to one of my classes so that it can be cancelled when/if necessary.
I'm going to use it in conjunction with +scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:

Should I be using strong, assign, copy, or unsafe_unretained for it? (with ARC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strong` for this. Typically you will also want to override the setter like this:

```
- (void)setTimer:(NSTimer *)aTimer {
  if (aTimer != _timer) {
    [_timer invalidate];
    _timer = aTimer;
  }
}
```

This way when you change or clear (nil) the timer, the old timer will automatically be invalidated (so it won't fire in the future).

The `aTimer != _timer` is there to avoid invalidating your timer if you do something like `self.timer = self.timer`. While you probably would never do that directly, it can sometimes happen indirectly.

Comment: Thanks. Is it standard practice to use _timer rather to self.timer in setters like this (in an analogous way to is done in the init/dealloc methods). (I'm assuming you've @synthesized the property as timer=_timer). P.S. Your book is my favorite iOS book and I have literally dozens of them.

Comment: Exactly as you say. Accessors should use their own ivar directly. Otherwise you can easily wind up with infinite loops (say the getter auto-initialized a default value, which is common). And yes, I'm assuming the necessary @synthesize. I'm glad the book has been useful. It's always nice to hear.